# Open document in my app from mail link in Android

Tags: android, email, pdf, android-intent, uri

User receives a mail in android, which contains a link. That link has to get a document (PDF) from the server (this is fine), but it has to open it directly in my app.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add an Intent Filter like the following to your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
    <data android:scheme="file" /> 
    <data android:host="*" />   
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Please note there is no way to force the system to open a pdf file in your app. If there are multiple apps that can handle the intent, the user will have to choose from a list.

Comment: Thanks. When will the user get the choice to select the PDF app? In the Browser? Is there another way to force the system to open it with my app, maybe without an URL?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the question in your first comment.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain it. What will happen, if I use your code above? When the user will open a PDF document, will he get a choice to open the PDF with: Adobe Reader, ThinkFreeOffice or MyAPP?

Comment: Exactly. If there are multiple apps that are able to open PDF files, the user will have to choose. However, if the user chooses to always open PDF files with an app, the dialog won't be displayed again.